# React Native: Set height of iOS native view equal to react native content height

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am pretty new to both React native and iOS. I have a native Scrollview A that contains another native Scrollview B and a ReactView (RCTRootView) as subviews one below the other. I need to set the contentHeight of Scrollview A to be equal to the content height of the Scrollview B and the ReactView.

To do this, I tried these two approaches:

1. Use 'onLayout' property to calculate the height of the top-level view in React Native and pass it on to native through the bridge and then set the contentHeight of the native view to be equal to this height. Although I receive the height in native, I find the native views to be nil when accessed from inside the bridge method: RCT_EXPORT_METHOD()
2. Set mode 'RCTRootViewSizeFlexibilityHeight' for the RCTRootView, set my view controller as the delegate and set native scroll view's content height based on react view height changes as explained here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html#react-native-content-with-flexible-size. But with this approach, when I set the 'RCTRootViewSizeFlexibilityHeight' mode, the react view just doesn't show up and also the delegate doesn't get called as expected.

What am I doing wrong in these approaches ? How can I achieve this ?